# React 16 - Incorrect Peer Dependency

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

After migrating to React 16 I got a lot of warnings which say that there is an incorrect Peer Dependency.

How can I avoid these with yarn?

I tried removing all packages, removed yarn.lock, and added yarn again.

```
 warning "react-textarea-autosize@4.3.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react@>=0.14.0 <16.0.0".
warning "react-modal@2.4.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0".
warning "react-modal@2.4.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0".
warning "react-komposer@2.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14.7 || ^15.0.0".
warning "react-treebeard@2.0.3" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^15.5.4".
warning "react-treebeard@2.0.3" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^15.5.4".
warning "babel-loader@6.4.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@1 || 2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc".
warning "chai-enzyme@0.8.0" has unmet peer dependency "cheerio@0.19.x || 0.20.x || 0.22.x || 1.0.0-rc.1".
warning "chai-enzyme@0.8.0" has incorrect peer dependency "enzyme@1.x || ^2.3.0".
warning "chai-enzyme@0.8.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-0".
warning "chai-enzyme@0.8.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-0".
warning "react-element-to-jsx-string@5.0.7" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14.8 || ^15.0.1".
warning "dirty-chai@1.2.2" has incorrect peer dependency "chai@<1.10.0 || >1.10.0 <4".
warning "material-ui-icons@1.0.0-beta.17" has incorrect peer dependency "material-ui@^1.0.0-beta.16".
warning "react-addons-test-utils@15.6.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^15.4.2".
warning "sass-loader@6.0.6" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^2.0.0 || >= 3.0.0-rc.0 || ^3.0.0".
```

Comment: This question might help answering yours:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42361942/when-installing-packages-with-yarn-what-does-incorrect-peer-dependency-mean

Answer (score 7):

Run 'yarn upgrade'. It should resolve many of the incorrect dependencies. Then you should change versions of the rest packages to the appropriate ones, but expect some packages to be out of date.