# What does 'has unmet peer dependency' mean when installing a package with yarn?

Tags: yarnpkg

I have a fresh install of `yarn` (via `npm install yarn -g`) and tried to install a few packages with

> yarn add vue-loader babel-loader style-loader css-loader file-loader webpack

I then got a few warnings during the installation, such as

> warning "vue-loader@13.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "vue-template-compiler@^2.0.0".

A [sister question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764881/why-does-npm-install-say-i-have-unmet-dependencies) (about `npm`) on the same subject yields a few answers which suggest to

1. update `npm`
2. remove `node_modules` as there is a bug in `npm` about handling dependencies.

I cannot discard the packages in the warnings, as the `webpack` build fails, which leads to me having to manually install them. At the same time, quite a few dependencies were installed so I do not understand why these were not installed.

What does the above warning mean, and why doesn't `yarn` install these dependencies on its own?

Comment: I am not a native speaker and I have just observed "X has unmet peer dependency Y" message on my laptop. Until I googled this SO question I thought the sentence meant "[installing] X has caused dependencies of Y not to be met", while they mean "X has got unmet peer dependencies..."

Comment: Potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42361942/when-installing-packages-with-yarn-what-does-incorrect-peer-dependency-mean?rq=1

Answer (score 76, accepted):

### What is a peer dependency

[Here](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/dependency-types) is some useful reading on dependency types, and [here](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/) is info on peer dependencies, but to summarize:

**Dependency**: A library/package your project needs to run.
**Peer dependency**: Used to indicate a library/package your project will hook in to.

The package `vue-loader` has a peer dependency on `vue-template-compiler` - `vue-loader` acts as a plugin for `vue-template-compiler`

### Why aren't peer dependencies installed by default

Peer dependencies were automatically installed up until [npm@3](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/110924823920/npm-weekly-5) (which yarn has followed in). This was stopped due to frequently confusing behavior. For example, installing another plugin with a conflicting requirement would result in an error.

> We will also be changing the behavior of peerDependencies in npm@3. We won’t be automatically downloading the peer dependency anymore. Instead, we’ll warn you if the peer dependency isn’t already installed. This requires you to resolve peerDependency conflicts yourself, manually, but in the long run this should make it less likely that you’ll end up in a tricky spot with your packages’ dependencies. [Feb 13, 2015]

### Update

As per [here](https://github.blog/2020-10-13-presenting-v7-0-0-of-the-npm-cli/) npm@7 now installs peer dependencies.
For the motivation behind this decision see [here](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/latest/implemented/0025-install-peer-deps.md)

Comment: It's just a warning but normally if a dependency is not met the execution will fail. So why does it seem possible to just ignore this warning?

Comment: What am I supposed to do? I'm using yarn. Should I ignore this or manually install?? You have only mentioned about npm's update not about yarn. Question is about yarn.

Comment: Nothing about yarn! The question is for yarn not npm.

Comment: @JeanPaul 2 possible reasons. Firstly if the peer dependency is optional. Secondly if the peer dependency is a dependency of some other installed package, but not listed in package.json, you'll still see the warning even though the package is available.

Comment: You can use [this tool](https://yarnpkg.com/package/check-peer-dependencies): 
`npx check-peer-dependencies` to check the missing peer dependencies, or use `npx check-peer-dependencies --install` to automatically install all of them.  Should work on both yarn and npm.

Comment: @Akhila for yarn users, add the unmet peer dependency like this `yarn add '@babel/core@^7.0.0-0'` (replacing @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 with the name of the unmet peer dependency from the warning message. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75500818/5783745).

Answer (score 15):

Running `yarn install --check-files` or just `yarn install` can fix the issue and install the missing depecendencies.

Explicitly adding to your `package.json` may also be an option.

Reference https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4594#issuecomment-763475899

Comment: No any of these `yarn` commands worked for me, the warning dependency is still there.

Comment: Adding the missing package to the `package.json` should always work, even if it is suboptimal

Answer (score 10):

As others have mentioned, peer dependencies are other packages required by a library that must be added to the dependencies of *the parent package* rather than directly within the library.

To resolve this warning you should run `yarn add <package>` for each `<package>` that is complained about. Below is an example.

Original output from `yarn install`:

```
$ yarn install
yarn install v1.22.15
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > react-markdown@8.0.3" has unmet peer dependency "@types/react@>=16".
warning "react-scripts > eslint-config-react-app > eslint-plugin-flowtype@8.0.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/plugin-syntax-flow@^7.14.5".
warning "react-scripts > eslint-config-react-app > eslint-plugin-flowtype@8.0.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@^7.14.9".
warning "react-scripts > react-dev-utils > fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.5.2" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>= 2.7".
warning "react-scripts > eslint-config-react-app > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.21.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
Done in 8.91s.
```

Commands to resolve the warnings:

```
yarn add '@types/react@>=16' '@babel/plugin-syntax-flow@^7.14.5' '@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@^7.14.9' 'typescript@>= 2.7' '@babel/core@^7.0.0-0' 'typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta'
```

You can now run `rm -rf node_modules/ && yarn` to test if the output is clean:

```
$ yarn
yarn install v1.22.15
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 9.05s.
```

Note that you may notice that you have to repeat this process if your newly added dependencies have any peer dependencies.

Comment: In the snippet where you recommend what to `yarn add ...` that includes many/all packages that should be `yarn add -D ...` instead.

Comment: This worked for me.  Thank you for writing up this clear answer.