# What should I do about "warning ... unmet peer dependency" when using yarn?

Tags: yarnpkg

I used yarn to install almost 1000 js libraries. When it's done I run `yarn install --check-files` and it warns me that it left out just a few. I find this bizarre that it installs almost all and only warns about not installing a small handful (but I'll [read up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46928390/what-does-has-unmet-peer-dependency-mean-when-installing-a-package-with-yarn#comment114982226_48767033) on why yarn's doing that later), for now, I need to figure out what to do about these unmet peer dependencies?

#### Example output

```
yarn install --check-files    
yarn install v1.22.19
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning " > babel-loader@8.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0".
warning " > babel-plugin-polyfill-corejs2@0.3.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning " > babel-plugin-polyfill-corejs3@0.6.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning " > babel-plugin-polyfill-regenerator@0.4.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning " > bootstrap@4.6.2" has unmet peer dependency "popper.js@^1.16.1".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
✨  Done in 1.52s.
```

My guess is simply install them with

```
yarn add @popper.js@^1.16.1
yarn add @babel/core@^7.0.0-0
```

I'm not totally sure though and want to get it right (also not sure if the first `@` and `^` should be there).

#### Note

Although I already mentioned it above and link to it, I reiterate, that this question differs from *[What does 'has unmet peer dependency' mean when installing a package with yarn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46928390/what-does-has-unmet-peer-dependency-mean-when-installing-a-package-with-yarn)* in that it asked about what a peer dependency is, whereas I (and [90 others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46928390/what-does-has-unmet-peer-dependency-mean-when-installing-a-package-with-yarn#comment114982226_48767033)) would like to know what must be done with yarn to ensure all (peer) dependencies are installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does 'has unmet peer dependency' mean when installing a package with yarn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46928390/what-does-has-unmet-peer-dependency-mean-when-installing-a-package-with-yarn)

Comment: @jonrsharpe no, I [linked to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46928390/what-does-has-unmet-peer-dependency-mean-when-installing-a-package-with-yarn#comment114982226_48767033) in the question above, that it doesn't help with what to do about it (explains what a unmet peer dependency is, sure, but my question is different to that)

Comment: _"it doesn't help with what to do about it"_ - yes, it does.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I edited the question to explain how the question I link to is different.

Comment: That question is _also_ covered in the answers on the dupe (both implicitly - as once you know why it's telling you that, what to do about it is pretty obvious - and explicitly).

Answer (score 2):

#### How to solve

Copy the name of the unmet peer dependency from the warning message, and add it using yarn like so:

```
yarn add '<unmet peer dependency>'
```

don't forget the `'` and `'` around the dependency, (and keep the `@` and `^` symbols if the unmet peer dependency has them).

#### Example

The error message in the question has

```
warning " > babel-plugin-polyfill-corejs2@0.3.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
```

so you'd run

```
yarn add '@babel/core@^7.0.0-0'
```

to add it.

Repeat this until all the warnings have gone when you run `yarn install --check-files` and the output just looks something like this (no warnings any more):

```
yarn install --check-files     
yarn install v1.22.19
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
✨  Done in 1.54s.
```