# Cannot get rid of yarn incorrect peer dependency warnings

Tags: node.js, react-native, dependencies, warnings, yarnpkg

After running `yarn upgrade` and installing the peer dependencies in my package.json, I cannot get rid of the warnings. I understand that warnings [won't actually stop my code from running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42361942/when-installing-packages-with-yarn-what-does-incorrect-peer-dependency-mean), but I'd like to try to minimize them as much as possible so that there are no warnings and clean installation looks nice.

**Here is my package.json**

```json
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "node ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-native": "^0.44.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-0",
    "@expo/samples": "2.1.1",
    "expo": "^31.0.2",
    "react-navigation": "^2.18.2",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "install-peers": "^1.0.3",
    "jest-expo": "^31.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.0.0",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-native": "^0.57.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

**terminal:**

```sh
$ trash yarn.lock; trash node_modules; yarn
yarn install v1.12.3
info No lockfile found.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
warning jest-expo > jest > jest-cli > prompts > kleur@2.0.2: Please upgrade to kleur@3 or migrate to 'ansi-colors' if you prefer the old syntax. Visit <https://github.com/lukeed/kleur/releases/tag/v3.0.0\> for migration path(s).
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning "expo > react-native-reanimated@1.0.0-alpha.10" has incorrect peer dependency "react@16.0.0-alpha.6".
warning "expo > react-native-reanimated@1.0.0-alpha.10" has incorrect peer dependency "react-native@^0.44.1".
warning " > react-native@0.57.7" has incorrect peer dependency "react@16.6.1".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
✨  Done in 19.19s.
```

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of this warning for example:

> react-native@0.57.7" has incorrect peer dependency "react@16.6.1"

Try command

```
npm install react@16.6.1
```

because react-native has a dependency on react's particular version.

Comment: The OP was asking about *yarn*.  NPM doesn't really help here.

Comment: @daotoad ```yarn add react@16.6.1``` is the Yarn equivalent

Comment: This can work but it frequently just ends up exposing A LOT more peer dep problems.